# Trying to compile software with "make -j4". Getting errors that I cannot make sense of

Tags: c++, xcode, makefile

A lot of solutions I've found specify going to Build Settings in Xcode, but I don't have Xcode installed on my computer, just the developer tools (the reason being that I couldn't install Xcode for the life of me). After running make -j4, I get to 71% completion until I get to:

```
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/testJson
```

Where I get these errors for numerous files:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/username/path/to/installation/directory'
ld: library not found for -lstdc++fs
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I do not know what these errors mean, so I do not know how to fix it. Perhaps if I remove the "-L" option this will fix it, though I don't know if this is the entire problem. I learned that -lstdc++fs is a compile flag. Is there a way to turn this off without Xcode installed? As for the clang error, I'm not sure where to even begin.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I think the message "directory not found" should be pretty clear. The linker can't find the directory `/Users/username/path/to/installation/directory`.

Comment: You're right, and I'm trying to go through the scripts and see where this path comes up so I can replace it. I don't know if this will fix the other issues, though maybe it will.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Can you provide a link to the install version you are trying to use?

Comment: Hello @Vroomfondel. The problem went away for now. Not sure how, but I deleted everything and started over and now the problem is gone. Thank you for asking, though.